# Ruby GIS - Converting NAD83 to WGS84

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapping, gis

I'm in the processing of developing a GIS component for our product and I have the need to convert NAD83 to WGS84.

Does anyone know of any Ruby libraries that are available that do this?  Or experience with anything that might do this?  I had previously done this using a library in .Net/C#, but so far I haven't had much luck tracking down an equivalent library.

I've already got the GeoRuby gem installed, but that doesn't seem to cover this type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Proj4rb](http://rubyforge.org/projects/proj4rb/) is a Ruby binding for [Proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/), which is the de facto library when it comes to converting between arbitrary projections and datums.

Comment: Yang, have you used Proj4rb?  I'm having some difficulty getting it to run on my WinXP PC and I've been unable to get the gem installed on my Ubuntu 9.04 laptop.

Comment: Unfortunately no: I've only used the Python binding for PROJ.4.

If the Ruby binding doesn't quite work, you can always try calling the proj commandline tool from Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

A little more searching turned up [Proj4](http://proj4rb.rubyforge.org/), which appears to offer this functionality.